# How to check whether there is internet connection with the device: cocos-2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, internet-connection

In one of my iPhone app, I need to find out whether there is internet connection with the device or not. Anyone pls help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Reachability class.

```
  if([self checkInternetConnected] ) 
  {
    NSLog(@"Internet connected\n");
  } 


- (BOOL)checkInternetConnected 
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];  
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus]; 
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

You can get rechability class [here : Download sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) and add Reachability.h and Reachability.m into your project.

Comment: And then you must add: SystemConfiguration.framework if you haven't added it yet! Good luck