# How to add interstitial admob ads to my ios project

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, admob

I want to add interstitial admob ads to my iPhone and iPad project, is there any working sample or tutorial?

**Edit:
I've successfully added it to my project, but if I don't have any internet connection the app stuck in the loading image, what should I do?**

Please do not provide Android links... We are talking about iOS.

Thank you!

Comment: you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397054/how-to-check-whether-there-is-internet-connection-with-the-device-cocos-2d

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Google Mobile Ad SDK, Google provides an excellent guide [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced).

If you prefer example projects, Google supplies one [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/downloads/list) *(currently called InterstitialExample_iOS_2.6.zip)*.

Comment: Hi, i've successfully added it to my project, but if I don't have any internet connection the app stuck in the loading image, what should I do?

Comment: @EdenNahum: you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397054/how-to-check-whether-there-is-internet-connection-with-the-device-cocos-2d